# Returning a value_counts() column when using nlargest()

Tags: python

I am returning the ratings of features for a business by demographic and ratings conditions. I would like to include the variable names used in the value counts output. Specifically, how do I include the variable name `Design` in the output?

```
# Cols I want to see the ratings for
ranked_cols = [
    "Design",
    "Food",
    "Wi-Fi",
    "Service",
]

# Select the relevant customers
sub = df[
    (df["Customer Type"] == "Disloyal")
    & (df["Satisfaction"] == "Not Satisfied")
    & df["Age"].between(30, 40)
]

(
    sub.melt(value_vars=ranked_cols)
    .groupby("variable")
    .value_counts()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"value": "rating", 0: "count"})
)

[Out]

    variable  rating  count
0   Design    2       5
1   Food      0       1 
2   Service   4       1
3   Wi-Fi     2       3
```

If I assign the melt to a variable e.g. `prod=( sub.melt(value_vars=ranked_cols)`, I can query the product with the highest count of 2 ratings, but it does not return the variable name `Design`:

```
prods[prods.rating == 2]['count'].nlargest(1)

[Out]

2     5

Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `prods[prods.rating == 2].nlargest(1, 'count')`. You are selecting the `count` column therefor there is no variable column at this point.

Comment: @MYousefi Thanks. That's incredibly simple. Naturally now I see it's located in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html#), but I had no clue that I could use the same method to access that column. I have edited and separated this into a single question so if you add your answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `prods[prods.rating == 2]['count'].nlargest(1)`.

There are 3 things happening.

1. Filtering the frame by `prods.rating == 2` which is ok.
2. Selecting the `count` columns which is not ok.
3. Getting the top 1 largest.

After step 2 the resulting table only has the `count` column and not the vaiable column.

Instead you want to tell `nlargest` to use `count` as its sorting criteria but not change the columns of the frame itself.

Using `prods[prods.rating == 2].nlargest(1, 'count')` does that.